# Saddle points and the second derivative changing sign

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f$ be a some real-valued function differentiable at least three times (I want to say twice, or maybe twice with a continuous second derivative, but I'll play it safe).

A *saddle point* of $f$ is some value $c$ in its domain, not a local extremum, which satisfies $f'(c) = 0$.

Proposition: $c$ is a saddle point of $f$ if and only if $f'(c) = 0$, $f''(c) = 0$ and $\exists \epsilon \in \mathbb{R_+}$  such that $\forall y \in (c - \epsilon, c)$ and $\forall x \in (c, c+ \epsilon), f''(x) \cdot f''(y)≤0$.

In other words, the second derivative "changes sign" at $c$. Intuitively, I am hypothesizing that a point is a saddle point iff it's a critical point and an inflection point.

Does this hold?

Comment: Consider the function $f(x) = \begin{cases} (x+1)^3, & x<-1 \\ 0, & -1\le x\le 1 \\ (x-1)^3, & x>1\end{cases}$.  What type of point is $(0,0)$?

Comment: (I deleted the previous comment). But could you elaborate, perhaps?

Comment: This function is at least twice differentiable (I think it's probably three times differentiable, but I'm too lazy to check now).  The point $(0,0)$ is certainly not an extremum, thus by your definition it is a saddle point.  But taking $\epsilon < 1$ we get $f''(x)\cdot f''(y)=0$.

Comment: @Bye_World Was my definition of a "saddle point" careless? I never considered constant functions.

Comment: It's fine -- I believe that's the usual definition.  But I just showed an example where you can have a saddle point that is not an inflection point. So your proposition is false.

Comment: @Bye_World Can this be remedied by changing the strict inequality "$<$" to $≤$?

Comment: @Bye_World Or, define the $\epsilon$-neighbourhood such that $c$ is the only value in that neighbourhood in which the second derivative vanishes. Though I can see why you might not like me redefining my statement simply to account for your counterexample! I can concede in its current form it's not exactly true, but surely you understand the gist of what I'm trying to get at.

Comment: I'm sure you can modify your definition so that it's true.  Possibly in either of the two ways you mention.  Why don't you try to prove one of them yourself?  First try to think up any counterexamples.  If you don't find any then try to prove it.  Remember an equivalence statement $A \iff B$ is proven by checking that both $A\implies B$ and $A\impliedby B$ hold.

Comment: @Bye_World Yes, of course. That is what I am attempting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function $f(x):=x^n\sin{\displaystyle{1\over x}}$ $(x\ne0)$, $\ f(0):=0$, with $n\geq2$ to your liking.

Concerning you comment below: It's not clear what your exact definition of a saddle point is. In any case, if $f(0)=f'(0)=0$ then the following formula, obtained through partial integration, may be of interest to you:
$$f(x)=\int_0^x(x-t)f''(t)\>dt\ .$$

Comment: I understand; the function's derivative vanishes at 0 but it's not an extremum. And the second derivative will change sign infinitely in any neighbourhood about 0. So this is a valid counterexample.

Comment: But, if I may ask another question, is there a counterexample for the biconditional in the other direction? Namely, you have something satisfying the condition but which is not a saddle point.